# Intermittent Error: ReferenceError: [functionName] is not defined, when using libraries

Tags: google-apps-script, libraries

I have  standalone apps script project that is a library for many other container-bound scripts.

Everytime the library is initialized, I want to load the properties service, so I have it setup like this:

```
initialize();
    
function initialize() {
   loadPropertiesService();
   *do other stuff*
}

function loadPropertiesService() {
  *do stuff*
}
```

This works 99% of the time, but occassionally I get an error stating "ReferenceError: loadPropertiesService is not defined"

It seems to me that maybe Apps Script is not hoisting the loadPropertiesService() function every time and sometimes can't find it?

UPDATE:
I have moved the call to initialize() from the global context to inside the function that is being triggered from the GAS trigger event in the container-bound like so:

```
function onEdit(event){
  Library.intialize();
  *do other stuff*
}
```

I am no longer receiving the reference error, so this seems to have fixed the immediate issue.  However, it would be nice to know why GAS is occassionally struggling to call this function from the global scope when the script initializes.

Comment: I unfortunately can't reproduce the error on my end. Are you able to reliably reproduce the error under specific circumstances? In addition, the `initialize()` function was getting called twice when I tested your script as a library. If that is not intentional, do try to remove `initialize();` and see if you can reliably replicate the error.

Comment: @DuuEyn I can't reliably reproduce the error either.  It seems to happen at random under varying circumstances.  A sinlge call can work 93 times without issue, but on the 94th time, that same call could fail with the reference error, so it seems random.  For now, I am trying to NOT calling initialize() from the global scope.  Rather I am calling initialize() from the top of the function being called by the trigger.  With that, I'll see if the reference errors persist.